# Function of lexicographic indices describing a permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, permutations

We choose a set number $N$ of elements for our permutations. Now we choose one of the $N!$ permutations and call it $P$. Having $2$ permutations $\pi_1, \pi_2$ than $\pi_1 * \pi_2$ is $\pi_2$ is applied on $\pi_1$. $L(\pi)$ is the (zero based) lexicographic index of $P$.

Now we want to find a function $f: \{0, 1, ..., N! - 1\} \to \{0,1, ..., N! - 1\}$ such that $f: L(\pi) \mapsto L(\pi * P)$.

This function can obviously be calculated by finding the lexicographic index of $\pi * P$, but i am looking for an algebraic (?) representation.

For example, if $N = 4$ and our chosen permutation $P$ is $(1, 2, 4 ,3)$ (swapping the last 2 elements). Then the function $f$ could be described as follows:
$$
f(i) = i +
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } i \equiv 0 \mod 2\\
    -1,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Functions similar to this can be found for all $P$ where $L(P) < (N-1)!$ (so the first element does not change its position).

One property that seems to hold for all $f$ is that $f(i) + f(N! - 1 - i) = N! -1$. Furthermore you know that the order $|P|$ (the smallest $k$ such that $P^k = \text{identity permutation}$) of $P$ is equal to the order of $f$. Since $f$ is a permutation itself and in its cyclic notation it will only consist of cycles of length $|P|$.

In our example $|P| = 2$ (since we only swap 2 elements) and the cyclic notation of $f$ would look like this:

$$ 
(0, 1)(2, 3)(4, 5)... (22, 23)
$$

For all other permutations i was not able to find any pattern or function and i could only find papers on how to find the lexicographic index of a permutation or generate them in lexicographical order but not what i am searching for.

Hopefully someone here can help me out or give me some pointers on where to find further readings.

Thank you for your help!